# Android NDK: why ndk-build doesn't generate .so file and a new libs folder in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I followed the steps of this tutorial: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/ to install the Android NDK on my Mac (not a PC => I didn't install CygWin)

When I run "ndk-build" in the console in my project folder (actually I have to type /my_path_to_my_ndk_folder/ndk-build otherwise I get "-bash: ndk-build: command not found" error message but anyway...) the console directly returns the prompt without any message confirming that everything is ok or that an error occurred ; according to the above mentioned tutorial, I should have a message like mentioned here: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/20.jpg

Finally, the problem is that I don't have any libs folder or .so file generated in Eclipse.

Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try running it in the 'jni' folder, not the project root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As originally put in a comment)

Try running it in the 'jni' folder, not the project root.

Comment: I am doing the same what you have mentioned still its not working for me.

Comment: I tyr to generate .o file using idk-build by my terminal in my mac PC but i got some strange error like ::   /Users/Desktop/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: internal error in do_print_to_mapfile, at /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../binutils/binutils-2.25/gold/output.h:395
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status